# Rotate and translate a single image at the same time in java

Tags: java

I am making a snake game for my project, and i have a question regarding rotating and translating images at the same time. My snake follows the cursor in any direction it goes, and i want to rotate its head by an angle which cursor executes. I have tried alot using affine transform but the problem is we can use either rotate or translate function at a time but not both. I have given the code, the snake body and its movement is handled by the paint component and i m confused what changes should i make to get the required result as i stated above. i have gone through documentations and questions posted on stack overflow but i got no solution

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

//class starts
//this class actually contains the game
//the object of this class is created in Snake_Menu class to start the real game
public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();// main frame
    int x_Cur; // x_position of cursor
    int y_Cur; // y_position of cursor
    int delta_x, delta_y; // difference between x positions and y positions of
                            // cursor and snake head
    int x_positions[] = new int[3600]; // array for storing x positions of body
                                        // segments
    int y_positions[] = new int[3600]; // array for storing y positions of body
                                        // segments
    int food_x, food_y; // storing x,y positions of food
    double x_inc, y_inc;// the increment added in head positions
    int segments;// defines length of snake body
    double angle;// calculated btw cursor and snake head
    double speed = 5.0;// speed of snake
    static int counter = 0;
    int rand_loc = 500;
    BufferedImage body;// image object for body
    BufferedImage head;// image object for head
    BufferedImage bgimage;// image object for background
    Sound sound = new Sound();// object of "Sound" class
    JLabel score = new JLabel("Score:" + sc);
    JPanel controlpn = new JPanel();
    static int sc;
    static int wr = 1;
    static int start;
    JLabel pause;
    int flag = 0;
    private JLabel resume = new JLabel("Resume\r\n");
    private JLabel Back = new JLabel(" Back");
    {
        try {
            // initializing image objects
            body = ImageIO.read(new File("./Images/Body.png"));
            bgimage = ImageIO.read(new File("./Images/Back.jpg"));
            head = ImageIO.read(new File("./Images/head.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Images not found");
        }
    }

    /******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<<Constructor called by class "Snake_Menu">>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    // constructor starts
    public Game() {
        // sound.music_stop();//slows down background music when playing game
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jp.setForeground(new Color(220, 20, 60));
        jp.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        // jp.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 500);
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pause = new JLabel("Pause");
        pause.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
        pause.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        pause.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            // actions taken when mouse enters or exits or clicked on the bounds
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                pause.setForeground(Color.red);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                pause.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        });

        resume.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
        resume.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        resume.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            // actions taken when mouse enters or exits or clicked on the bounds
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                resume.setForeground(Color.red);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                resume.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                flag = 0;
            }
        });

        Back.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
        Back.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        Back.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            // actions taken when mouse enters or exits or clicked on the bounds
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                Back.setForeground(Color.red);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                Back.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                sound.music_stop();
                Snake_Menu sn=new Snake_Menu();
                sn.frame.setVisible(true);
                jf.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        controlpn.add(Back);
        controlpn.add(resume);
        controlpn.add(pause, BorderLayout.WEST);// add to frame
        controlpn.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));

        score.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
        jp.add(score, BorderLayout.WEST);
        jp.add(controlpn, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jf.getContentPane().add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // frame properties
        jf.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.addMouseMotionListener(this);// adding mouse motion listener to frame
        jf.addMouseListener(this);// adding mouse listener to frame
        jf.setFocusable(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(700, 650));
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        first_Snake();// this method initializes first snake
        sound.music_Bg(); // Sound Class method for playing background music
    }// constructor ends

    **/******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<<Paint Component>>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    // paint starts here
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(bgimage, 0, 0,700,650, this); // drawing background image
        g2d.drawImage(body, food_x, food_y, 31, 31, this); // food image
        // this for loop paints the body
        for (int z = 0; z < segments; z++) {
            if (z == 0) {
                // do nothing
            } else if (z == 1)
                g2d.drawImage(body, x_positions[z], y_positions[z], 31, 31,
                        this);
            else
                g2d.drawImage(body, x_positions[z], y_positions[z], 31, 31,
                        this);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        meet_Food();// checks whether the head has met with food or not
        /*********** this block defines the motion of snake ************/
        delta_x = x_Cur - x_positions[0];
        delta_y = y_Cur - y_positions[0];
        angle = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        double speed = Math.sqrt(delta_x * delta_x + delta_y * delta_y);
        speed = Math.min(speed, 3.0);
        if (flag != 1) {
            x_inc = (speed * Math.cos(angle));
            y_inc = (speed * Math.sin(angle));
            x_positions[0] += x_inc;
            y_positions[0] += y_inc;
        }
        counter++;// to give a gap between body segments
        // when x_positions[0] is incremented 7 times
        // then its value is passed to its body segments
        // to have a space in segments of body, counter does that job
        if (counter % 7 == 0) {
            if (!(delta_x == 0 && delta_y == 0)) {
                // this for loop transfer the positions of head to its body
                for (int z = segments; z > 0; z--) {
                    x_positions[z] = x_positions[z - 1];
                    y_positions[z] = y_positions[z - 1];
                }
            }
            counter = 0;
        }
        /*************************** block ends ***********************/
        if (start == 1)
            repaint();
    }// paint ends**

    /******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<<first_Snake method;initializes first snake>>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    public void first_Snake() {
        segments = 3;
        for (int z = 0; z < segments; z++) {
            x_positions[z] = 60 - z * 20; // giving space of 20 pixels btw every
                                            // segment
            y_positions[z] = 60;
        }
    }// first_Snake ends

    /******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<< locate_Food method; to locate food at random after snake eats it>>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    public void locate_Food() {
        food_x = (int) (Math.random() * rand_loc);
        food_y = (int) (Math.random() * rand_loc);
    }// locate_Food ends

    /******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<<Checks whether snake has met food or not>>>>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    public void meet_Food() {
        for (int y = 1; y < 31; y++) {
            if ((x_positions[1] >= food_x && x_positions[1] <= food_x + 31)
                    && (y_positions[1] + y >= food_y & y_positions[1] + y <= food_y + 31)) {
                sound.music_Eat();
                sc += 5;
                score.setText("Score:" + sc);
                segments++;
                locate_Food();
            }
        }
    }// meet_Food ends

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    /******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    /* <<<mouseMoved method to get location of mouse>>> */
    /*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        x_Cur = me.getX() - 20;
        y_Cur = me.getY() - 40;
    }// mouseMoved ends

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        start = 1;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
}// class ends
```

Comment: Look man, please post some short verifiable code. You just needed help with the image issue... so why post the whole juggernaut? If you can post a hello world with the issue, we could give it a try...

Comment: the issue is in the paint component you don't have to look whole code

Comment: i just need help with rotating and translating images at same time, so that my snake can move and rotate its head. what exactly would we use to do that, we don't have to look at the code for that

Comment: see [this](https://www.snake.si/snakeclassic/) snake game, i m trying to do the same